# image hiding text, it should take different line

Tags: html, css

The problem is my image is on top of text. What I want is that text dodge the image and the text that is hidden by image take different line. how is it possible?

Following is my CSS

```
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -90px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -90px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element
  has position: relative; This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">
    <img src="http://localhost:20162/images/logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem reproduction at [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gs5y0ewz/).

Comment: You shouldn't be using `position: absolute` if you want to content to flow around the positioned element, since `position: absolute` takes that element out of the document's flow. Does the element have to be in that precise position, or simply moved to the right hand side of the other content? Can you adjust the margins or padding?

Comment: What is the size of the logo? Use lorem pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep it in the flow if you want it to interact with other content.

float will do this for you, but it requires floatting elements ahead in the flow.

an extra element or pseudo to drop it down 20px can be used . example:

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.relative:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 20px;/* + prepare mimic top:20px */
}
div.absolute {
  float: right;
  clear: left;/* do the mimic top:20px */
  width: 200px;
  margin-right:-90px;/* mimic right:-90px */
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
    <img src="http://localhost:20162/images/logo.png" />
  </div>
  This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element
  has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;

</div>
```

edit: [jsfiddle going along](https://jsfiddle.net/gs5y0ewz/2/)

Comment: This is the better solution if you want to have full control over the exact position of your div +1

Comment: can you add explanation to this line `clear: left;/* do the mimic top:20px */` what does it take if I want to mimic 40px or 70px, etc, how does `clear` property work?

Comment: if you don't clear it, the right flow will be right from the left flow, 0 px from the top. A clear takes it out of the flow, and puts it on a 'new line', so to say. Best explanation you'll find by just trying out :)  Just change the height of the .relative:before to mimic a different top for your div that contains the image.

Comment: @Erik ok, and now I am confused about `.relative:before` :)> why we need to insert `before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 40px;/* + prepare mimic top:40px */
}` to create space on the right from the top `20px`?

Comment: I think you will understand best if you play a bit around with the code on fiddle. Give the :before some pixels height and width, and a background color, and check the behavior when making changes in the code. As far as I know you won't be able to get the top position without the extra element. The float makes it part of the flow, the text will go around, and if you then push your image div down the text will stay as it was, (around the area where your div was before your 'downpush') and your div will be over your text anyway. Well, it's not easy to explain: play around and you'll understand!

Answer (score 2):

That won't work with a div that's positioned `absolute`.
Should be `relative`, and have a `float` for the text to go around.
Then you can put the `div` in the text where you want to have it.

So maybe this is okay for you?

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.absolute {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right:-90px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position:<div class="absolute"><img src="http://localhost:20162/images/logo.png"/></div> relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;This div element has position: relative;
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gs5y0ewz/1/

If the exact position is important, and you don't want to move your image around when text is added or removed, you should definitely go for GCyrillus' answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `position: absolute;`
an element with a position of absolute can be placed anywhere on the page, even on top of other elements. you should either move it by changing

```
right:-90px;
width: 200px;
```

or by changing it's `position` attribute.

Comment: absolute position to which element?